# Best practice to define a large, complicated HTML structure as a link?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Consider the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>Item 1</h2>
        <p class="subline">Meta information bla bla</p>
        <div class="description">
            <p>Paragraph one</p>
            <p>Paragraph two</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <!-- More ... -->
</ul>
```

I'd like to link each of the `li`s to a link. As proof of concept, I give you this invalid code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=test+1">
            <h2>Item 1</h2>
            <p class="subline">Meta information bla bla</p>
            <div class="description">
                <p>Paragraph one</p>
                <p>Paragraph two</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- More ... -->
</ul>
```

Obviously, this won't validate because I can't have block-level elements inside inline elements.

> **EDIT: As it turns out, the code above is valid in HTML5. Problem solved.**

I need to find another solution:

#### Insert an `a` tag into each block level element

I considered adding identical `h2 > a`, `p.subline > a`, and `div > p > a` tags, but I'd like to have a hover state using `:hover` that affects the whole area of the link, so that won't work.

#### Using an onclick event

I have used Javascript to solve this problem before (`li.onclick = function() { window.location.href = ...`), but then I can't use the middle mouse key to open in a new window. This affects usability, depends on Javascript, and is, frankly, super annoying.

#### Making the block-level elements inline:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=test+1">
            <span class="title">Item 1</span>
            <span class="subline">Meta information bla bla</span>
            <span class="description">
                <span>Paragraph one</span>
                <span>Paragraph two</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- More ... -->
</ul>
```

Most likely, `display: block` would need to be applied to some of or all of those spans to make them behave.

This is valid HTML, but it's really kind of awful.

Does anyone know the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Why must the whole thing be a clickable link? Why not just the title or something?

Comment: Both of the solutions are good for different scenarios. If you want to build a Web 2.0 application (like StackOverflow), the second one based on AJAX is probably better. If you do not want to depend on JS, it might make sense to keep the title as a link for backwards-compatibility. On the other hand the <span> solution is better for a general application. Again as with BoltClock, why do you need it to be all clickable?

Comment: I want the whole thing `li` to be a clickable link because I want the user not to have to figure out which is the clickable part. Also, I like the feel of a big link with some hover feedback. [Here](http://gregmoonart.com/art)'s an example of what I mean. Also, check out the sidebar on [this page](http://cumbrestoltec.com/special-trains) for another example.

Comment: HTML5 allows block level linking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use HTML5:

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links

> HTML5 presents a simpler line of thought with HTML than XHTML.  And quite honestly, it's a much needed simplification.  One of those simplifications is the ability to wrap block-level elements like DIVs, H-tags, and P's with basic A elements.  You read that correctly:  wrap block-level elements with A tags.

Personally, I've never worried about this. Yea, it's technically invalid, but I'm a fan of pragmatic validation.

Comment: It's technically invalid in HTML5? How?

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it, but this validates! `<!DOCTYPE html><title></title><a href="#"><div></div></a>`. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: sorry, technically invalid x/html. I don't usually worry about that kind of markup being invalid, as browsers are 'cool' with it. Nice that HTML5 fixes that.

Comment: I like my pages to validate to avoid problems. Also, I like the idea of having standards that everyone follows that ensure a more predictable web for developers. That said, I do understand your point. I also break the rules for small stuff like a `target` attribute in XHTML.

Answer (score 3):

I totally sympathize with your frustration.  I think you've summed up the problem and the common approaches to address it well.  I've gone both routes you've suggested in various situations.

First, another, even more problematic(!) option.  I don't condone the following as a best practice!  ...But you could add it to the list that may fit in limited circumstances.

http://jsfiddle.net/peteorpeter/J4sT9/

Basically, if you can stomach using hefty portions of absolute positioning and fixed heights, you can make the title a link and cover the other elements.  It's quite fragile and rigid, really.  You also can't have a background on the link or it will obscure the other elements.

Ok, once you get the puke taste out of your mouth after looking at that mess, I think you should:

- Embrace the nice semantic markup you started with
- Add a link in it somewhere that looks pretty and clickable
- In JS, hide the link above and route clicks from the `<li>` to the hidden link
- In JS (or CSS 2+), enhance the hover effect on the `<li>`

Slightly altered markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>Item 1</h2>
        <p class="subline">Meta information bla bla</p>
        <div class="description">
            <p>Paragraph one</p>
            <p>Paragraph two</p>
        </div>
        <a class="link-for-no-JS" href="buystuff">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <!-- More ... -->
</ul>
```

Nothing too groundbreaking there, just basic progressive enhancement.  Folks with less capable browsers have to hunt for a link and might not get any hover effects (but it could still be a handsome, usable interface); folks with more advanced browsers get an even more intuitive and responsive experience.

Comment: This would be my approach (+1), and I'll note that not putting a background on the link is not such a bummer -- you can put the BG on the li; and if you need a hover state, then use JavaScript (jQuery!) to add the effect to the parent on the link-hover -- "propagating it to the li using Javascript" as Spliff writes (he gets +1 too)

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have solved this exact issue by putting the link in the heading then propagating it to the li using Javascript. That way most people get the desired effect and if JS is off it works anyway. When you propagate the link set a class as well. It's a little extra complexity but it is valid HTML. Depends on your priorities.

```
// psuedocode
on document ready {
   els = getElementsByClassName("mylinks")
   for el in els {
      li = el.parentNode.parentNode;
      li.onclick = function() {window.location = el.href}
      li.className = "liHover";
   }
}
```

Comment: I've already considered this solution. See the "Using an onclick event" section of my original post.

Comment: Do note that links were never meant to contain paragraphs of information. From an accessibility POV, you probably don't want to have all that text inside a single `<a>` tag. As such, I'd second SpliFF here and consider the JS option.

Answer (score 0):

There is another hack which depending on situation can work. Pull the `a` element out of the natural rendering flow using `position: absolute` and make it's height and width large enough to cover the area in question. A high `z-index` value can also come handy. It's a hack though.